# Django class-based view

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

## Django

Following the official documentation, I am creating a Django app (the same poll app as in the documentation page). While using the class-based view, I got a error. I did not understand much about class based view, for instance, may someone explain, what is the difference between a class based view from a normal view?

Here's my code:

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Poll
    template_name = 'polls/details.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        
    def detail(request, poll_id):
        try:
            poll = Poll.objects.get(pk=poll_id)
        except Poll.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404
        return render(request, 'polls/details.html', {'poll': poll})

*********************Error ********************
TypeError at /polls/2/results/
as_view() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    <app-path>/polls/2/results/
Django Version: 1.5.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
as_view() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)    

*****the url***
 url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view, name='detail')
```

Comment: Please post the complete code you are using, as this snippet won't work because you have a basic syntax problem (you have a def statement without any body).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`as_view` should be called, not referenced, according to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/#simple-usage-in-your-urlconf), your url should look like:

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail')
```

Note the usage of parenthesis.

Also, you should rather call your class `PollDetailView` to avoid confusion for code readers.

Also, the `detail()` method you have defined will not be called at all. So you shouldn't define it at all. Also, leave the `get_queryset()` method alone for the moment, try to get the basic View to work first.

Comment: ``def detail(request, poll_id):`` also needs to be ``def detail(self, request, poll_id):``

Comment: and you have an empty `get_queryset(self)` method that's probably going to raise errors after you fix the parameters problem

Comment: @krak3n: are you sure that `generic.DetailView` will call `def detail()` at all ? This method defined by the TO seems completely useless...

Comment: Well yeah but I assume it's there for a reason, if it's not then remove it otherwise if it's gonna be used it will need self. :)

Answer (score 3):

When you use url for the CBV ensure that you can not use the reference of the of the url filed, so first you need to add change the as_view to **as_view()**.

And you can use DetailView like this.,

```
   class PollDetail(DetailView):
   model=Book

   def get_context_data(self,*args,**kwargs):                    
       context=super(PollDetail,self).get_context_data(*args,**kwargs)
       print(context) #It will give you the data in your terminal
       return context
```

And for accessing data you need to use **{{object}},**

and if you want to access other fields at that time use like this **{{object.fieldname}}**

In CBV the template name is automatically named as per class name so you don't need to give it.

Note:Don't give class name same as DetailView,In future you will confuse.

Comment: also we can override template rather than use of default.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not modifying the view functionality, to use this generic view, you can simply do this:

in your `urls.py` (along with other stuff):

```
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from poll.models import Poll

url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
    DetailView.as_view(model=Poll,
                       template_name='polls/details.html'), name='detail')
```

Then in `poll/details.html`, you just need:

```
{{ object }}
```